# How to create vertically responsive web-pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a single page web page but the problem is I am using `margin-top` with `em`to space some of the elements vertically. On some screens it is pushed down too much and out of view forcing the user to scroll down. This is not acceptable to me. I tried using media queries but the problem is using `screen only` does not really work always because tabs, address bar, bookmark bar,etc also take up space. I am just confused on how to do this. Please help.

Comment: Use rem instead of em

Answer (score 0):

If you have shared the code, I would have got the clear picture. anyway, following css should help you to have a container/wrapper that's height is as long as the window and all the elements inside the container will be placed in the center vertically and horizontally.

```
.container {
    height: 100vh;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;   //center vertically
    justify-content: center;  //center horizontally
}
```